# Why C# is an open standard but .NET is not?

Tags: c#, .net, ecma

Why C# is an open standard but .NET is not? What is the point in this? Why Microsoft decide to open only some part of their .NET?

Comment: C# is an open standard so others can write compilers that will compile the language.  As for .NET being an open standard - what exactly would be standardized about it?  The API docs are available to anyone, so anyone could implement the classes in it to build a compatible library (e.g. Mono)

Comment: API docs being public doesn't mean you're allowed to create your own clean room implementation based solely on the documented behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Various parts of the .NET runtime are indeed standardised by ECMA just like C# - CIL, the CLI, the CLS.

Answer (score 7):

.NET is the *runtime* and C# is the *language*. C# can be compiled and run on other runtimes, such as Mono. I am actually not aware of any other runtimes besides Mono, but since the spec for C# is open, you could read it and make your own runtime. ;)

Comment: You could also not employ a runtime at all. There's nothing stopping you from statically compiling C#.

Comment: There's also Rotor, a shared source implementation of the CLR.

Comment: Microsoft released the source code for another implementation of the first versions of the standards: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3A1C93FA-7462-47D0-8E56-8DD34C6292F0&displaylang=en - kind of irrelevant today compared to Mono, which is much more up to date.

Comment: @Lucero: I'd never heard of DotGNU before. How compatible is it with WinForms? I have some C# projects that if I could compile them for Linux with *minimal* code changes, it would be nice. I remember trying something like it with SharpDevelop/Mono and too many things broke.

Comment: @Frustrated: If you take a WinForms project and can compile it for another platform with minimal changes, all you'll end up with is a crappy cross-platform application.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I'd proabably be willing to live with a crappy cross-platform app if it's not *too* crappy. It's a personal project used > 90% of the time by myself, and having a linux version would be a nice little convenience, even if the UI is not quite the same. Really, I'm just too lazy to rebuild my UI from scratch with a different framework. :P

Comment: @Frustrated: the DotGNU is much less mature than Mono and more focused towards web services and applications. Maybe you should give Mono another try, they are making significant progress in many areas, WinForms included.

Comment: I think C# may was intended to be usable on platforms unrelated to .NET, and constructs like C# destructors seem motivated by such intention; do you know if any use of C# for code not targeted for .NET or a clone thereof?

Answer (score 4):

C#, like Java, C, C++, etc. is just a language definition. In and of itself, it does nothing. It defines the means by which a user can define a program or procedure and interface with external libraries.

The .NET framework, on the other hand, is not a language. It's a class library and development framework.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is an open standard ([ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf) for the runtime api instead of [ECMA 334](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) for the language).

Going beyond this, [the source code for Microsoft's implementation of .Net is available](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) and there are [multiple separate implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Alternative_implementations) (the most prominent of which by far is [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)).

There is some additional concern about patent encumbrance.  However, Microsoft has also issued a [legally binding and irrevocable community promise](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/cp/default.mspx) on the .Net platform that covers both specifications (a lot of people miss the legally binding part).

Comment: Note only a subset of the .NET library sources are available.  Furthermore, the source code to the CLR is not/probably will never be released - Microsoft released a "reference implementation" but not the real one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the framework.  I guess they want to maintain control over the library implementation on Windows.  There is nothing stopping someone from implementing a call-compatible version of all or part of the framework based on their own source as was done by Mono.

Comment: Also many pieces of the .NET Framework is only meaningful on Windows, but a good open standard should be platform independent.